# Is Indiana Handgun Permit Valid, If I'm no Longer a Resident?

Tags: licensing, firearms, indiana

Indiana offers a lifetime handgun permit to Indiana residents, per [IC 35-47-2-4 (a)(2)](http://iga.in.gov/legislative/laws/2021/ic/titles/035#35-47-2-4):

> Licenses to carry handguns shall be either qualified or unlimited, and are valid for ... the life of the individual receiving the license in the case of a lifetime license.

However, I can not find any indication of the validity of the permit (and therefore its reciprocity with other states) if the resident relocates out of Indiana. The closest I can find is [IC 35-47-2-3(g)(4)(B)](http://iga.in.gov/legislative/laws/2021/ic/titles/035#35-47-2-3):

> ...a lifetime license is automatically revoked if the license holder does not remain a proper person.

However, I do not believe that "Indiana Residency" is a requirement of being a proper person, as it is not mentioned in the definition of "Proper Person" at [IC 35-47-1-7](http://iga.in.gov/legislative/laws/2021/ic/titles/035#35-47-1-7)

...So that leaves me at a loss. **Do those holding a Lifetime Indiana Handgun Permit retain said permit, even after Indiana Residency?**

Comment: Are you asking if your permit would be valid should you return to Indiana, or are you asking if it's valid in your new state of residence?

Comment: @Michael Particularly focusing on if it's valid in any case whatsoever, now that I'm not an Indiana resident. As in, if I show a Florida Officer my Indiana License to Carry, is that license valid, even though I am now a resident of Florida (which reciprocates validity with Indiana licenses)

Comment: Could you add the definition of "Proper Person" to the question (the link has a geoblock)?

Comment: @MarkJohnson it's a very long section, but broadly, a person who is not been convicted of any of several crimes, not delinquent on child support or taxes, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be any indication I could find that your Indiana license would expire or be revoked. That said, that question is likely moot for your purposes per the comment you left. **Your Indiana permit is no longer valid in Florida if you have been a Florida resident for 91 days or more.**

Florida handgun license reciprocity is covered by [S 790.015](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0700-0799/0790/Sections/0790.015.html) and applies to non-residents. Individuals who establish residency in Florida and have a license from another state have 90 days to acquire a Florida license (emphasis mine):

> (3) **If the resident of another state who is the holder of a valid
> license to carry a concealed weapon or concealed firearm issued in
> another state establishes legal residence in this state** by:
>
> (a) Registering to vote;
>
> (b) Making a statement of domicile pursuant to s. 222.17; or
>
> (c) Filing for homestead tax exemption on property in this state, **the license shall remain in effect for 90 days following the date on which the holder of the license establishes legal state residence**

Comment: This does allude to the practical application of how it would affect me - still I wonder, is the Indiana license revoked from Indiana?

Comment: @TylerM I wonder too. In many (32) states it is possible for non-residents to apply for and hold licenses, so it's not outside the realm of possibility that the license would remain valid. Hopefully someone else does come along with a conclusive answer.